# Right-click is executed only once

Tags: windows, forms, winforms, cefsharp

I want to simulate a right-click several times (three times). The right-click is executed only once. What can I do to make the right-click run three times?

```cs
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = 300, y = 300;

            chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseMoveEvent(x, y, false, CefEventFlags.None);
            chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Right, false, 1, CefEventFlags.RightMouseButton);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Right, true, 1, CefEventFlags.RightMouseButton);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            x -= 50; y -= 50;

            chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseMoveEvent(x, y, false, CefEventFlags.None);
            chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Right, false, 1, CefEventFlags.RightMouseButton);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Right, true, 1, CefEventFlags.RightMouseButton);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            x -= 50; y -= 50;
            chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseMoveEvent(x, y, false, CefEventFlags.None);
            chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Right, false, 1, CefEventFlags.RightMouseButton);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Right, true, 1, CefEventFlags.RightMouseButton);
        }
```

Comment: Initial though is you are changing the coordinates, you haven't actually moved the mouse. The `WPF` project uses `SendMouse*` methods internally, I'd suggest you add some logging and capture the output to get a better idea of what is expected.

Comment: I expect to see the context menu at three different positions but it's displayed only once.

Comment: And I'm suggesting you send mouse move events in between,.

Comment: That's what I've tried too but it doesn't work :-(

Comment: Please edit your code to show the updated example.

Comment: Okie, dokie, sure.
Done.  :)

Comment: Mouseleave should be false

Comment: Okay, I've edited the code but it doesn't help, unfortunately. The context menu is shown only once.